# VS2017 / Git commit error (.gitconfig - no such file or directory)

Tags: visual-studio

Trying to use the GIT integration inside of VS2017 to commit my solution changes to our .NET core API solution , VStudio gives me the following error:

Git process failed unexpectedly.
error: could not lock config file //.gitconfig:: No such file or directory
error: could not lock config file //.gitconfig: Invalid argument.

What does this error indicate?  How do I correct?

VS2017 v15.2 (26430.14)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14960629/5951133), I ran into this problem last week and setting the HOME variable fixed it