# Jenkins unable to find .gitconfig

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-config

I am trying to execute the following command from jenkins

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

But i am getting the following error

error: could not lock config file %USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig: No such file or directory

Jenkins configuration:
Slave: Windows machine,
Build step: Execute shell

I tried the following:
Changed the file permission,
Deleted the file and tried,
Manually edited the .gitconfig to have the expected configuraiton.

I am really not sure what is causing this error. Is this because of the path (%USERPROFILE%)?

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: Please, try to execute command `echo %USERPROFILE%` and post the result. Most likely it's not a problem with file but this env variable cannot be resolved

Comment: yes, the file is present in the path (c:/Users/[user-name]/.gitconfig

Comment: Hi @AleksanderStelmaczonek, When i did echo %USERPROFILE% am getting the output as 
 "%USERPROFILE%" . (build-step: execute shell). 
 "C:\Users\user-name" . (build-step: Windows batch). Both results in the same failure

Comment: Just to resolve any misunderstandings. Please, do the same for `echo $USERPROFILE`

Comment: @AleksanderStelmaczonek echo $USERPROFILE result : C:\Users\user-name

Comment: Do I understand correctly your previous comment that you still failed to execute your original command even in Windows batch build step?

Comment: @AleksanderStelmaczonek yes. Both in windows batch and execute shell, i am getting the same error

Comment: Then it's really puzzling. It seems like it's not an issue with env variables. Please, try searching for issues with .gitconfig locking. For example check if there is a file named `.gitconfig.lock`.

Answer (score 0):

First, check this is not related to [JENKINS-21376](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21376):

> "Force polling using workspace" Allows my poll to suceed and the build to be triggered automatically.

Check [your `HOME`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120277/6309), the presence of a special character in the path or a [process locking `.gitconfig.lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47081855/6309)