# How to fix Git for Windows error: "could not lock config file C:/file/path/to/.gitconfig: File exists"?

Tags: git

While trying to set up Git with my GitHub account the following error keeps persisting whenever I try to do a global config.

It works fine for repositories, but the global doesn't work.

Here's how it shows:

```
$ git config --global user.name "username"
error: could not lock config file C:/Path/to/.gitconfig: File exists
```

I'm using Git 2.21.0 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: That error might mean that the file is already locked for editing by another process. There are several ways to find and kill the process that has it locked, but the easiest solution is a reboot. It might also be a permissions error, in that git has read-only access to the file and thus can neither edit nor replace it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble setting up git with my GitHub Account error: could not lock config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959972/trouble-setting-up-git-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+could+not+lock+config+file+.gitconfig+File+exists

Answer (score 11):

Check your folder where the `.gitconfig` file is located, and if there is a `.gitconfig.lock` file, delete it. I got the same error and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 11):

Since you're on Windows 10, it could be an issue if your .gitconfig is located at C:.  If that's the case, try running your git bash with Administrator privileges (right-click on your executable, select More > run as Administrator) and see if that works. You need administrator privileges to work on files at the root of C:. That worked for me.

Comment: At least now, 3 years later, I can add the following: If the error says "File exists" then there's no permission problem. In that case, just delete the gitconfig.lock file. If the error says "Permission denied", then use an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

In other situation, If you don't have `.gitconfig.lock` file, there should be a `config.lock` file in `.git` folder of the repo.
You can delete this file and It will fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue and the "problem" was a security configuration in Windows, Folder lock or something like that. It is under Settings > Windows Security > Protection History. If you allow the access, it should work just fine