# Can't set git config values - could not lock config file: File exists

Tags: git, git-config

I'm trying to set git config values but I keep getting `could not lock config file` error whenever I try to update them. I've looked around on Stack Overflow and followed the advice to try and remove .gitconfig so that I can recreate it. However, I then get the error `No such file or directory`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

```
MacBook-Pro-10:~ Chris$ git config --global user.name "Chris Marshall"
error: could not lock config file /Users/Chris/.gitconfig: File exists

MacBook-Pro-10:~ Chris$ rm ~/.gitconfig
rm: /Users/Chris/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Check the permissions on your home directory, but even with those being weird, you should not get this particular set of errors. Check to see if `~/.gitconfig.lock` exists as well: that might explain the problem. Git should be complaining about that path, but there's some squirrelly code here.

Comment: That's worked thank you! It was the `~/.gitconfig.lock` that was causing the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Git for Windows error: "could not lock config file C:/file/path/to/.gitconfig: File exists"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327408/how-to-fix-git-for-windows-error-could-not-lock-config-file-c-file-path-to-g)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22error%3A+could+not+lock+config+file%22+%22.gitconfig%22+%22File+exists%22