# Lack of global gitconfig file

Tags: git

By a mistake i deleted my global git config file. When i`m trying to commit something i need to identify with command:

`git config --global user.email "name@example.com"`

or

`git config --global uswe.name "name"`

but i get information

`error: could not lock config file C:/Users/acer/AppData/Roaming/SPB_16.6/.gitconfig: No such file or directory`

I tried to recover that file but couldn`t. How to recreate that file and what should it include.

Comment: Does this article help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959972/trouble-setting-up-git-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-file

Comment: Ohh, how could i miss that. Just tell me please if i undestand it properly. In my case .gitconfig didnt create exacly in $HOME$ directory but somewhere deeper, in this directory SPB_16.6, so when i just simply recreate SPB_16.6 and use ``` git config --global user.email "email" ``` it will work again?