# Not able to set user.name and user.email using Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash

I am not able to set my Git credentials

```
$ git config --global user.name "Akshy,Sash"
error: could not lock config  file C:/User/Sash/$USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig
```

I am able to set it using command prompt but when I use Git Bash I get the "could not lock config" error.

Comment: look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959972/trouble-setting-up-git-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble setting up git with my GitHub Account error: could not lock config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959972/trouble-setting-up-git-with-my-github-account-error-could-not-lock-config-file)

Comment: Even if I try to follow those steps I get /h/%USERPROFILE%/.git:No such file or directory

Comment: Then you should give more details.

Comment: I am able to set user,name and user.email using command prompt but not able to do it with git bash,but if i do it  with cmd  it is not set globally by and every time i try to push a code it says username ,useremail not present

Comment: and git config -l does not list my user.name or user.email

Comment: Check this :
https://github.com/rprichard/wslbridge/issues/32